# How to turn this code into a 1 liner without losing efficiency?

Tags: python, optimization

To improve the readability, I'd like to turn this code into a 1-liner.

The variable `tup_ranges` is a a tuple of 2 values, e.g. `(20, 40)`. If the value of `elt` is included in this range, then the key corresponding to this value `n` is retrieved.

```
identification = dict()
for elt in combination:
    for n, tup_range in ranges.items():
        if tup_range[0] <= elt and elt <= tup_range[1]:
            identification[elt] = n
```

Somehow, I can't figure out a good writing for this piece of code...

```
identification = {elt: [n for n, tup_range in ranges.items() if tup_range[0] <= elt and 
                        elt <= tup_range[1]][0] for elt in combination}
```

Works but is slower because of the list created in the middle... Anyway to get rid of this list which only has one element anyway?

To try it out:

```
ranges = {25: (20, 32), 35: (33, 45)}
combination = (30, 30, 40)
# Output:
{30: 25, 40: 35}
```

P.S: Indeed this question would have its place on code review, but I feel like it's mostly a misdesign of the dictionary-comprehension.

Comment: `to improve the readability`? You probably mean worsen

Comment: Nested comprehension is definitely less readable, are you sure it should be a one-liner?

Comment: @yatu ok, let's say for personal reasons :)

Comment: FWIW: `tup_range[0] <= elt <= tup_range[1]`…

Comment: @deceze Yes the and is irrelevant. Still, the main problem of the dictionary comprehension is that I created a list of 1 elt every time. 120 ns for the for-loop code, and 4.4 us for the dict comprehension...

Comment: `[{k:i for i,j in ranges.items() if j[0] < k and j[1] > k} for k in combination]` gives you a list of the dicts - still slower than the loops though

Comment: @jeremycg Thanks, indeed slower. I am really surprised by this huge difference in efficiency between the loops implementation and the dict-comprehension :/

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to benchmark?

Comment: @lucasgcb %timeit in an IPython Console (Spyder and Python 3.7). Nothing fancy.

Comment: @lucasgcb Damn I'm stupid. Figured out the difference, simply wrongly used the %timeit. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mathieu It happens :) If you could write it into a separate answer for the records that'd be nice, or edit into Devesh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more readable version of your one-liner might be

```
identification = {elt: n for n, tup_range in ranges.items() for elt in combination if tup_range[0] <= elt <= tup_range[1] }
#{30: 25, 40: 35}
```

Or

```
identification = {elt: n for n in ranges for elt in combination if ranges[n][0] <= elt <= ranges[n][1] }
```

Just tried to time both approaches

```
ranges = {25: (20, 32), 35: (33, 45)}
combination = (30, 30, 40)
identification = {}
import time
start = time.time()
for elt in combination:
    for n, tup_range in ranges.items():
        if tup_range[0] <= elt and elt <= tup_range[1]:
            identification[elt] = n
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
#1.2159347534179688e-05
```

```
ranges = {25: (20, 32), 35: (33, 45)}
combination = (30, 30, 40)
identification = {}
import time
start = time.time()
identification = {elt: n for n in ranges for elt in combination if ranges[n][0] <= elt <= ranges[n][1] }
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
#5.0067901611328125e-06
```

The dict comprehension is 10x faster

Comment: Indeed, it's a lot better! However, it is still far less efficient. I get to 2.6 us (vs 4.4 us for my version of the dict comprehension). The for loop code runs in 120 ns...

Comment: How efficient are you looking for?

Comment: Well, especially since this is an elementary step repeated thousands of times, it has to be efficient. I am really surprised that the dict-comprehension takes 10x to 20x longer to complete that the same code written with loops.

Comment: Solved, the efficiency is the same, I misused the %timeit to measure the first one.

Comment: And that's not a reliable way to measure the time taken by a function. Both are now same speed, thanks :)

Comment: Ohh how do you measure it? I ran both codes independently

Comment: Depending on your CPU load, e.g. you code youtube/spotify or whatever in background, you can get completely different results on independent runs. Thus usually, you want to try thousands, to millions of runs and compute the mean and std. To do so easly, you can use %timeit in an IPython console. An equivalent without the IPython console is to use `timeit.timeit`.Output: `3.27 µs ± 357 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`